# Segmentation Fault 11 while scanning a string

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, malloc, scanf

This is a part of my code:

```
int main() {

    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number < 5) {
        printf("%d", 0);
        return 0;
    }

    int lengths[number];
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < number; j++){
        char str[6];
        scanf("%s", str);
        lengths[j] = strlen(str);
        printf("%d ", j);
    }
```

There's more under the code I posted here, but since they don't seem important, I omitted them.

The problem is that, while scanning strings, Segmentation Fault 11 appears when scanning the last string. For example, my input was `"Pen Pine Apple Apple Pen"`, it scans only first 4 words, and then the seg fault appears.

Could you tell me what's the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try `scanf("%5s", str);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If you enter a string longer than 5 characters you'll run into trouble, because `str` can only hold strings up to 5 chars long (6-1 because of the NUL string terminator).

Comment: First you need to enter a number (5).

Comment: Entering `5`<Enter Key>`Pen Pine Apple Apple Pen`<Enter Key> works fine for me and there is no reason why the program should fail with that input. What is your _exact_ input?

Comment: If you enter just `Pen Pine Apple Apple Pen`, then the first `scanf` fails, `number` will contain an indeterminate value and I let you imagine the rest.

Comment: `int lengths[number];` will not be of length 5 if you type '5' because it is initialized at main entry.

Comment: Oh, I've found what is the matter. Thank you!